# count() gives me wrong output after while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, count

I'm fetching data from my database and `count()` gives me a wrong output after fetching the data in a while loop. Why?

Output is:

```
Line: 1 
Line: 2
Count after loop: 3
```

Code:

```
while($line[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo 'Line: '.count($line);
}
echo 'Count after loop: '.count($line);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the 3rd iteration [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-array-returnvalues) will return NULL, since there are no rows left, which you then add to the array.

On NULL which evaluates to FALSE the while loop will stop, but it gets added to the array. So you then have 3 elements, e.g.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => something
    [1] => something
    [2] => NULL
)
```

You can see this when you do: `var_dump($line);`. Also to solve this now, you can simply put the code in the while loop to add the element, e.g.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $line[] = $row;
    echo 'Line: '.count($line);
}
echo 'Count after loop: '.count($line);
```

So with this you won't add `$row` to `$line` if `$row` holds NULL.

Comment: mhm, so i need to do something like this ?
while(($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL)'

Comment: @ZanKravitz Yes with this you prevent your code from adding NULL as the last element. Or you just `array_pop()` it off, when you use your original code. Or not so readable anymore: `while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) !== NULL && $line[] = $row)`